# Populate a 2D array from a dataset imported from excel using data without column headers

Tags: excel, vb.net, dataset, oledb

I'm trying to populate an array from a dataset imported from excel using data without column headers.  My code is as follows:

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection
Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dts As DataSet
Dim excel As String

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Try

        Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        With OpenFileDialog
            .InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
            .Filter = "All Files (*.*) | *.*"

            If .ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(.FileName)
                Dim FileName As String = .FileName
                excel = fi.FullName
                Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & excel & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
                conn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
                dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn)
                dts = New DataSet
                dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
                Dim arrCol0 As Double() = (From myRow In dts.Tables(0).AsEnumerable
                                           Select myRow.Field(Of Double)("[A]")).ToArray
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

The [A] in "Select myRow.Field(Of Double)("[A]")" appears to be required.  Is there a way to exclude the column heading?

Comment: Use the ordinal. Something like: `dim theColumnIndex as integer = 1 dim arrCol0 = dts.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Select(function(r)  Convert.ToDouble((r(theColumnIndex))).ToArray()` or `r.Field(Of Double)(theColumnIndex)` would do. Btw, if you just need one DataTable, fill a DataTable instead of a DataSet.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  What's the benefit of a DataTable over a DataSet?

Comment: You are using a DataTable. You do nothing with the DataSet. Since you don't actually use it, it's not useful to add the overhead: just fill a DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create the array based on the number of columns and rows in the `DataTable` and then you would traverse the `DataTable` and the array by column index and row index, e.g.

```
Dim arr(table.Columns.Count - 1, table.Rows.Count - 1) As Double

For columnIndex = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(0)
    For rowIndex = 0 To arr.GetUpperBound(1)
        arr(columnIndex, rowIndex) = CDbl(table.Rows(rowIndex)(columnIndex))
    Next
Next
```